How to Add new Azure VM into Custom Linux DNS server through ARM Template
We are using ansible for creating Azure VMs and adding the DNS records of Azure VM into the Custom Linux DNS server. Not Azure DNS.
Now migrating into ARM template for Azure VM creation. Is that any way to create A record into the Linux DNS server from ARM template ?
YAML
Copy
dns_host:  "hostname"
dns_zone:  ""
dns_type:  "A"
dns_IP:  "host_ip'"
Now migrating into ARM template for Azure VM creation.
Is that any way to create A record into the Linux DNS server from ARM template ? Thanks,
